# How to pass in scope for has_many scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Courier` object and I want to be able to call `courier.daily_orders` to find all orders from the current day assigned to the courier.

I have the following `has_many` scope below that isn't working.

```
has_many :daily_orders, -> {
  where('orders.bucket_time >= ? AND orders.bucket_time <= ?',
    courier.service_region.to_local_timezone(Time.now.beginning_of_day),   
    courier.service_region.to_local_timezone(Time.now.end_of_day)) },
  class_name: Order
```

**How do I pass in the `courier` object so that I can call `courier.service_region...`?**

Comment: Even though my answer will probably solve your problem, I've been thinking about your design. I'm guessing a `Courier` `has_many :orders`, if so, why not create a `scope` for the daily orders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
has_many :daily_orders, -> (courier) { where('...') }
```

or the verbose version of `lambda`

```
has_many :daily_orders, lambda { |courier| where('...') }
```

or `proc`

```
has_many :daily_orders, proc { |courier| where('...') }
```